# How can I get column name from correlation list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation

[image]

I want to get all column names that corr relationship is over 0.2 and lower than 0.8. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Well, can you get the rows where the value is over 0.2? Can you get the rows where the value is less than 0.8? Why not just put those two conditions together? If you aren't familiar with that, then you should probably just read a Pandas tutorial; this is about the most fundamental thing you can do with a Dataframe, and the reason to use Pandas in the first place. Where did you actually learn that there is such a thing as Pandas? You should go back there, and read the advice more carefully on how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can index the Series `corList` with conditions, and retrieve the names with `.index`:

```
corList[(corList > 0.2) & (corList 0.8)].index
```

Or a possible more readable version:

```
corList[corList.gt(0.2) & corList.lt(0.8)].index
```

Answer (score -1):

Using the example from the pandas docs, we can get the corr and filter with two conditions, take the index of the matches and output to list.

```
import pandas as pd
def histogram_intersection(a, b):
    v = np.minimum(a, b).sum().round(decimals=1)
    return v
df = pd.DataFrame([(.2, .3), (.0, .6), (.6, .0), (.2, .1)],
                  columns=['dogs', 'cats'])

c = abs(df.corr(method=histogram_intersection)['cats'])

print(c)
print(c[(c>.2) & (c<.8)].index.tolist())
```

Output

```
dogs    0.3
cats    1.0
Name: cats, dtype: float64

['dogs']
```